# what does this line of code "#define LIBINJECTION_SQLI_TOKEN_SIZE sizeof(((stoken_t*)(0))->val)" do?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, sizeof, dereference

In particular I'd like to know what `->val` does in the

```
sizeof(((stoken_t*)(0))->val)
```

and what `stoken_t*(0)` pointer do, in particular what the `(0)` means?

I hope I have formulated my question clearly enough.

Comment: Might be more readable to write `sizeof( (stoken_t){0}.val )`. Does the very same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a way of accessing a member of a structure at compile time, without needing to have a variable defined of that structure type.

The cast `(stoken_t*)` to a value of `0` emulates a pointer of that structure type, allowing you to make use of the `->` operator on that, just like you would use it on a pointer variable of that type.

To add, as `sizeof` is a compile time operator, the expression is not evaluated at run-time, so unlike other cases, here there is no null-pointer dereference happening.

It is analogous to something like

```
stoken_t * ptr;
sizeof(ptr->val);
```

Comment: With the edits my answer is superfluous, good explanation.

Comment: In general, dereferencing a NULL pointer causes undefined behavior. It's a bit surprising that this is well defined.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: This is not the case here since sizeof does not access the memory pointed to by the cast pointer.

Comment: @Peter Both answers were useful! So if I have understood correctly this code casts a numeric literal that can be any (e.g. (7) ) to a pointer in order to access a variable and consequently use the operator sizeof. And all of this to have it working at compile time and not at run time (I must study a bit about those two cases and how it changes)

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I thought I addressed that explicitly in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In detail:

`(stoken_t*)(0)` simply casts `0` (this could be an arbitrary numeric literal) to a pointer to `stoken_t`, `((stoken_t*)(0)->val)` is then the type of the `val` member of `stoken_t` and `sizeof` returns the number of bytes this type occupies in memory. In short, this expression finds the size of a struct member at compile time without the need for an instance of that struct type.